# Sequelize-Auto Override for MySQL View

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I am generating a model with the [`sequelize-auto`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) library and I am having trouble working with MySQL Views.

I have created a view and am generating a sequelize model from it. This view does not have a column called `id`. MySQL also does not allow for views to define primary keys. Because of how sequelize works, any model without a specific primary key defined, will have an `id` column added. This breaks the generated model.

I can fix this simply by amending my model by adding `primaryKey` flags to the fields that constitute a unique entry in the view. However, these changes will be overwritten each time I generate the model using sequelize-auto.

[`sequelize-v7-alpha`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/advanced/) adds the ability to define tables as having no primary key. So using MySQL views with v6 may be a specific limitation of the library.

What I would like to do is simply add some type of model override where after generating the `sequlize-auto` model from my database, I can specify what columns of what models to add properties to. However, I can't figure out any configuration that will do so. Does anyone know how to do this or a workaround for this type of situation?